# How to get the next match from a MatchCollection following after a specific Capture.Index with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I wanted to know how to get the next match from a MatchCollection following after a specific Capture.Index with Linq?

Let's say I have a MatchCollection "myMatches" and I know a specific Capture.Index of one match in it. I want to get the next match, it's value, in "myMatches" now but I don't get it how to write the Linq query...

```
string myNextMatch = myMatches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.NextMatch().Value).Where( ??? ).ToString();
```

I messed around with something like this but nothing works. Is there anybody here who can help? Thanks!

Comment: The [`Match.NextMatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch?view=netframework-4.8) method computes the next match. In your case you have already computed all the matches, and computing them once more seems like a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
string myNextMatch = myMatches.OfType<Match>().Single(m => m.Index == myKnownIndex).NextMatch().Value;
```

But be careful.. If Single() doesn't find any or more Objects, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly that what I want. Thanks @Machine

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `Linq` you can acces a specific match by index - or if it needs to be `Linq` you can use `Last()` to determine the last element:

```
string input = "ababab";
Regex regx = new Regex("a", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection myMatches = regx.Matches(input);
Match lastMatch = myMatches[myMatches.Count - 1];
string result = input.Substring(lastMatch.Index, lastMatch.Length); // ababab
                                                                    //     ^
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/sZH1wS

Comment: But it's not the index in the collection that I know, it's the capture.index of one match in the collection. So, it's the index of the position in the original string.

Comment: Ok looks like we have a xy problem problem here - what are you actually trying to achieve - could you add a example with input/expected output to the question

Comment: OK, let's use your example up there. The collection contains 3 matches (each 'a'). The match with the index 1 in the collection has the capture.index 2 (match.index). I wanted to get the next match in the collection now by using this capture.index to find it. Hope it's understandable.

Comment: @burnie just to be sure - what's the expected output?

Comment: In the example up there the expected output should be the last (third) 'a'. In the case the capture.index would be 2 ;)

Comment: So always the last match? something like `string myNextMatch = myMatches.OfType<Match>().LastOrDefault()?.Value;`

Comment: I thought it should be possible to get the next match in the collection only by using an match.index to find it. Every single match in the collection stores the index of the original string where the pattern was found. So, my idea is to get the match of the match.index I know and using NextMatch() (maybe?) the find the next match in the collection. Oh, this sounds pretty complicated, sorry, I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: The index doesn't tell you the length of the match. e.g. `[a-z]+` could be any length.

Comment: Is the length important to find the next match in the collection? I thought you can do somehing like look for match with match.index I know and then return me the next match in the collection. This is not possible in that way?

Comment: Ok let's say here you have the last index `int lastIndex =  myMatches.OfType<Match>().Select(x => x.Index).Last();` and you want to get the result from your initial string `"ababab"` How? `"ababab".Substring(lastIndex,?);`

Comment: Ah you mean because it could be out of range. That's not a problem in my case, there is always at least one more match in the collection of the match.index I know. But maybe your example just now helps to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. I messed around and this is what I want (almost)...

```
string myString = ">first match< >second match< >third match< >fourth match<";

MatchCollection myMatches = new Regex(">([^<])+<").Matches(myString);

// let's say this is the index I know, should be 29
int myKnownIndex = myMatches[2].Index;

// myNextMatch result will be ">fourth match<"
string[] myNextMatch = myMatches.OfType<Match>()
    .Where(m => m.Index == myKnownIndex)
    .Select(m => m.NextMatch().Value).ToArray();
```

But now my next question, is it possible to put the output directly into a single string and not using an array? It's only working right now exactly this way.